# Multivariate analysis for incomplete fractional factorial design

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, multicollinearity

We have conducted a survey experiment with varying amounts of incentive (factor 1 = I1, I2, I3, I4, I5). The experiment was conducted stepwise in three subsequent studies (factor 2 = S1, S2, S3). Unfortunately, the factors are not fully crossed. The experimental design is as follows:
[image]

Outcome variable of the planned analysis is recruitment for a panel survey (y=0,1) dependent on incentive group. I was wondering if it is statistically correct to include all five incentive groups and furthermore controlling for the point in time in one regression analysis. The five incentive groups  should be included as dummy variables in the regression analysis.
When constructing interaction terms of incentive group and study, one is confronted with the problem of multicollinearity. E.g., respondents of study 1 (S1) have no chance to be in incentive groups 3 to 5 by design. 
In the table below I have illustrated the data matrix with all 8 possible patterns. The model can be formally described as follows:
[image]
[image]

Is it correct to leave out incentive group 1 (I1) and study 1 (S1) as I have done?
Finally, I was wondering if the varying numbers of respondents per experimental group will be an issue besides less precise estimates for the groups with smaller numbers.